# pythonic approach to fixed-length strings given variable length input string

Tags: python-3.x, string

I need to take a variable-length string and make it a fixed-length for `struct.pack()`.

if the input string is:

- longer than `size`, then it needs to be truncated
- shorter than `size`, then it needs to be padded

there doesn't seem to be a one-line method for padding or truncating a string to a fixed length

what's simpler than this?

```
in_str='abcd1234'
size=12 # or 4
def make_str_this_len(in_str,size):
    if size<=len(in_str):
        out_str = in_str[0:size]
    else:
        out_str = in_str.ljust(size)
    return out_str

# printing string and its length
res=make_str_this_len(in_str,size)
print("resulting string:[{0}], len={1}".format(res,len(res)))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```py
def make_str_this_len(in_str,size):
    return in_str.ljust(size)[0:size]
```